# Running Eclipse under Valgrind

Tags: eclipse, valgrind

Has anybody here succeeded in running Eclipse under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)? I'm battling a particularly hairy crash involving JNI code, and was hoping that Valgrind perhaps could (again) prove its excellence, but when I run Eclipse under Valgrind, the JVM terminates with an error message about not being able to create the initial object heap (I currently don't have access to the exact error message; I'll edit this post as soon as I do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a crash in native code, then gdb might be a better choice.
It should even stop the execution automatically on a crash and might show You the stack trace (command *bt*).

Comment: I've tried that already. I found out that the crash occurs when a new thread is created, but before control has been passed to the JVM, i.e. the crash occurs somewhere inside glibc or pthreads.

Answer (score 2):

Does it work if you [run valgrind with --smc-check=all](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.java)?

Also -- valgrind increases a program's memory requirements pretty dramatically. With something as large as Eclipse, there's plenty of room for trouble; hopefully you're 64-bit  native (and thus have plenty of address space) and have lots of RAM and/or swap.