# Java JNI - associating resources allocated in C with java objects?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I want to allocate some memory in C and keep it associated with a java object instance, like this:

```
void configure(JNIEnv *object, jobject obj, ....) {
  char *buf = new char[1024];
  // associated <buf> with <obj> somehow
}
```

And then later free the memory when the java object gets garbage collected - I could do this by calling a JNI function from the **finalize()** method of the java object.

The question is, how do I associate a C pointer with the java object? Keep a **long** field in the object and cast the pointer to **long**? Is there a better way?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214699/jni-memory-management-using-the-invocation-api

Comment: Sort of, in that question there is no discussion of how to associate the C object to the java instance. In the example presented the pointer is cast to long. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally, if you want to transfer a pointer from C to Java, it's recommended to use `long` so that there are enough bits to hold the pointer value in case the platform is 64 bits.

Then, have a look at [`ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect(int)) which creates a `ByteBuffer` instance which memory can be shared with C. You can allocate such a direct `ByteBuffer` from the Java side then pass it as a `jobject` to a JNI function and inside this JNI function you use the [`GetDirectBufferAddress`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/jni-14.html#GetDirectBufferAddress) function.

Another way is to wrap a native area of memory with the [`NewDirectByteBuffer`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/jni-14.html#NewDirectByteBuffer) JNI function from the native side. It gives you a `jobject` you pass back to the Java side (pay attention to local and global references). Pay attention to the fact that once the direct `ByteBuffer` that wraps the native memory has been created, you are still responsible for managing the native memory: at some point, you will have to call `delete buf;` in your native code, Java won't do it for you.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, using ByteBuffer.allocateDirect() sidesteps the pointer passing + memory management; this way ByteBuffer manages the memory.

Comment: Allocating the direct ByteBuffer from the Java side let Java allocate the block of memory, which is going to be released when `finalize` runs. The only downside is that you don't exactly know when the garbage collector passes so you don't really know when the memory is released apart that it's going to be released after you're finished with the buffer.

Comment: der is way to load library ... is der any way to unload..?

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have any concept of native pointer, so storing it as a long is the only real option. But you should not rely on `finalize` to free the pointer; the finalize method is unreliable as a means of cleaning up resources. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158174/why-would-you-ever-implement-finalize) for further details.