# Do I need to free a ByteArray allocated in a SWIG out typemap?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I'm currently using SWIG to wrap a `unsigned char*` as a `byte[]`. I'm returning this type from C++ to the Java side of my code.

Thing is, I don't really know if the responsibility to free the memory for this array falls on the native code and / or wrap, or on the Java GC.

Right now I'm using this (don't mind the awful hack to get the size...):

```
%typemap(jni)     unsigned char * Image::getPixels "jbyteArray"
%typemap(jtype)   unsigned char * Image::getPixels "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype)  unsigned char * Image::getPixels "byte[]"
%typemap(javaout) unsigned char * Image::getPixels{
    return $jnicall;
}

%typemap(out) unsigned char * Image::getPixels {
    //There must be a proper way than using an implicit local variable name
    //from the generated cxx file...
    size_t length = arg1->getBpp() * arg1->getWidth() * arg1->getHeight();
    $result = jenv->NewByteArray(length);
    jenv->SetByteArrayRegion($result, 0, length, (const signed char*)$1);
}
```

Here, the `NewByteArray` looks completely in the wild, and I don't know if and where I should call a `ReleaseByteArrayElements`. I found [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9370066/1594913) but I'm not sure if that's exactly the same case here.

Comment: Looks ok to me. `$result` holds a local reference to the byte array, and you shouldn't have to explicitly delete local references unless you create so many of them (e.g. in a loop) that you risk filling the local reference table.

Comment: So when I do that: `jenv->NewByteArray(length)` and "return" `$result`, the JVM takes ownership of that memory and will GC it?

Comment: That's what would happen if you did this from a plain native function. So unless SWIG is inserting some additional code that creates a global reference behind the scenes, I'd say this code will work fine. I suppose you could do a test where you create a `NewObject` of some class of your own where you have overridden `finalize()` and log when the object gets finalized.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

`ReleaseByteArrayelements` is used with `GetByteArrayElements`, so you don't need it here.
You don't need to free anything. The array will be freed by the Java garbage collector once there are no references to it.